# Are the stunts staged or spontaneous?

Tags: stunts, jackass

Through the years of watching Jack-Ass, I've always wondered about some of the stunts they do. A few come to mind

1. When one of the guys goes into a hardware store to...use one of their display toilets.
2. When Johnny Knoxville goes into a motor cycle shop (in the old man costume) and then floors it through the front display window.

Were these really staged as shown (taking everyone by surprise) or did someone at the place of business know about it and give consent? If they gave consent, what incentives do they get for letting the show disrupt and possibly destroy their place of business?

Comment: At a guess I'd say they *have* to be staged to an extent. Obviously they really *do* those things, but the fact they film, for example, the guy on the display toilet, film the aftermath and the whole time the store owner doesn't do much suggests to me it's fake. I'd love to know for sure though. I'll definitely look into this one.

Comment: @AndrewMartin wasn't really sure how to phrase my question.

Comment: I think your question is fine to be honest. I'm just saying, without sources, that gut instinct says scenes with supposed *customers* HAVE to be fixed. But I wouldn't post that as an answer without a reference.